# Facebook PHP inform/notify friends to check their account on my website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Users of my Facebook app on my website will check some of his friends (no problem). Then I need to let them know they have new message from that user. How can I let them know about it? Notification? Private message? Post on their wall? I think notification (to globe top area) would be great but how to do it with PHP graph

Answer (score 0):

You should use Request Dialogs for this. See here:

[Facebook Request Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Comment: thanks for your reply but request dialog has limitation for count of users. And I need to do it in php because my idea is: User selects his friends in my app and I store this list in my db (for particular project) and then I send message/notification to all users from list. any idea?

Comment: you are not able to send notification for requests via api

Answer (score 0):

You can send notifications to people who have authenticated your app. Only problem is that this creates a notification that will only show up in the users "Apps and Games" notificatons - which doesn't create a red notification gem - it can easily remain unnoticed.

This is a function that will generate the requests for you:

```
  protected function sendFBNotification($user_id, $app_id, $app_secret, $message)
  {

    $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' .
            'client_id=' . $app_id .
                '&client_secret=' . $app_secret .
                    '&grant_type=client_credentials';

    $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);



    $apprequest_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/' .
              $user_id .
              '/apprequests?message='.urlencode($message).
              '&data=null&'  .
              $app_access_token . '&method=post';
    try
    {
      $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
      return json_decode($result, true);
    }
    catch(ErrorException $e)
    {
      return false;
    }

  }
}
```